# Google cloud functions - Promises causes execution error

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, es6-promise

I have a scheduled job in Google Cloud Functions that uses promises.
On first execution, after a new deploy, the code works, but all executions after first execution fail - both scheduled and triggered by "Test function".

I suspect my promises is the cause of the problem, but I cannot figure out where I am going wrong.

My code structure

```
googleCloufFunction.onRun()
  firebaseCall.once().forAll(note)
    Promise.all(lookupPromise)
    .then(addNotification) //return Promise.all(notificationPromises)
    .then(sendEmail) //return Promise.all(sendEmailPromises)
    .then(udpate note)
```

On first execution, I get the following logging

> console.log('lookupPromises - membersToAlert')
>
> console.log('lookupPromises completed')
>
> console.log('sendEmail')
>
> console.log('update database')
>
> ...

After first execution, the log stops after

> console.log('lookupPromises - membersToAlert')

My code

```
exports.notification_email = functions.region('europe-west1')
.pubsub.schedule('0 * * * *').timeZone('Europe/Stockholm')
.onRun((event) => {
  //Search for notes with passed alertDate
  database.ref('notes/').orderByChild('data/alertDate').endAt(moment().valueOf())
  .once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach( (data) => { 
      //Get membersToAlert and isAlreadyProcessed
      //...

      if (!isAlreadyProcessed) {
        //Get category name
        let lookupPromises = []
        console.log('lookupPromises - category name')
        //Push promise - returns category title for current node
        //...

        //Get membersToAlert email addresses and names
        console.log('lookupPromises - membersToAlert')
        membersToAlert.forEach((memberId, index) => {
          //Push promise - returns an object {userName, userEmail}
        })

        //Perform lookup and promise chain rest of the calls 
        return Promise.all(lookupPromises)
        .then((lookupArray)=>{
          //Collect variables from lookupPromises response
          //...
          console.log('lookupPromises completed')

          //addDbNotification performs and returns Promise.all()
          return addDbNotification(...) //Needs result from lookupPromises
        })
        .then(()=>{
          //Send email 
          console.log('sendEmail')
          //sendMail performs and returns Promise.all()
          return sendEmail(...) //Needs result from lookupPromises
        })
        .then(()=>{
          //Update database
          console.log('update database')
          return dbRef.update( {"sys/sentEmail": true} )
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
          console.log('notification_email Error', err)
          return false
        })

      }//End if (!alreadyProcessed)

      return true
    })//End snapshot.forEach

    return true
  })//End firebase .once()
  .then(()=>{
    return true
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
    console.log("Cronjob error", err)
  })

  // return true
})//End exports.notification_email
```

addDbNotification

```
const addDbNotification = () => {
  //This function needs data from "lookupPromises"
  let promises = [] 
  membersToAlert.forEach((memberId, index) => {
    //Push promises to 1. add notification and 2. update counter for each "membersToAlert"
  })
  return Promise.all(promises).catch((err)=>{
    console.log('addDbNotification Error', err)
  })
}
```

sendMail()

```
const sendEmail = () => {
  //This function needs data from lookupPromises
  let mailPromises = []
  //Push promise to send mail to each "mailRecipientsArray" 
  return Promise.all(mailPromises).catch((err)=>{
    console.log("sendEmail error", err)
  })
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to:

1. Find all expired notes
2. Process each note
3. Collect "categoryId" and "membersToAlert" for each note
4. Write alert and counter to database for each "membersToAlert" for each note
5. Send email to each "membersToAlert" for each note
6. Update the note in database when finished
7. Finish execution and cleanup

As of now, the log shows that the execution finishes too early

> hourly_job-notification_email [procId] Function execution started hourly_job-notification_email
>
> hourly_job-notification_email [procId] Begin hourly_job-notification_email
>
> hourly_job-notification_email [procId] Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value
>
> hourly_job-notification_email [procId] Function execution took 199 ms, finished with status: 'ok' hourly_job-notification_email
>
> hourly_job-notification_email [procId] lookupPromises - category name hourly_job-notification_email
>
> hourly_job-notification_email [procId] lookupPromises - membersToAlert hourly_job-notification_email

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: They key to finding such a problem is reducing the code to the minimum that is needed to reproduce the problem. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen! Thank you for your feedback! I have tried to simplify the code to better show the structure of the calls.

Comment: You need to return a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete in your function.  Right now, you're using the callback variant of once(), which makes this much harder.  once() returns a promise, and you should be using that in addition to all the other promises being generated in your code.  This video series might be helpful in understanding this better.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: What is `isAlreadyProcessed` and what are you using that for?

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 it is a flag to determine if the note should be processed or not.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson! I tried to use .once('value').then((snapshot) => {} but got warnings complaining about nested promises instead. Will take a look at the video series!

Comment: Too much code missing to follow the log file entries or following what might be happening.  For example, if `membersToAlert` is empty the second time or `lookupPromises` is empty the second time, then there wouldn't be much to do the second time.  Since you don't show any code that controls either of those, not much we can see here.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00! I tried to tidy up my code for better readability. I get you point though, the .then() will not trigger if lookupPromises is empty. In my case the ommited rows below console.log('lookupPromises - category name') always gets executed - so the lookupPromises will never be empty. :)